# Why is the border going outside of the parent?

Tags: html, css

Here's my test case:

http://codepen.io/jgclifton/pen/hKynd

I want the border on .outer to be container inside the .inner

Ultimately the effect I want to achieve is the lighter grey box is 10px thinner top and bottom than the dark grey box (so the thinner light grey box is in the middle of the dark grey).

Comment: you can't squeeze the parent element into its' own child and make it even smaller - change your markup

Comment: Do you want something like this: [LINK](http://codepen.io/joe/full/neBof)

Comment: exactly that - if you put it as an answer I will accept. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We just need to "play" a bit with the margin:

**css changes:**

```
.outer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
  border-top: 10px solid white;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.inner {
    width: 960px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #999999;
    margin: -10px auto 0;
}
```

We set the `.outer` div **10px** from the top and then the `.inner` div **-10px** from the top. Then of course if we change the size of the `.inner/.outer` elements we will also have to change their margin value.

Answer (score 0):

You have to control the overflow property of the outer. Like for example: `overflow: hidden;`.